# Sharepoint site ask for login when user reload page

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

My web application running on Sharepoint Foundation 2013, but recent, it prompt credential when user reload page or redirect to another page.

ie user loged in and working on it, but if user reload page or change page by clicking any link, it prompt user to enter user name and password

please help, thanks.